# Jquery convert array object into json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i am relatively new in Javascript and jquery.

I have create an array of object using serializeArray() ,

```
var form_data = $("some_id").serializeArray();
```

where form_data returns data in the folliwing format,

```
[obj, obj, obj, obj]
```

where each *obj* contains data in this structure,

```
0: object
   "name": "hotel_id"
   "value": "1"
```

but i want it to be return in the following format,

```
{"hotel_id": "1"}
```

to do so i have tried the following code initially to either return the `name` or the `values`

```
var myArray = $.map(form_data, function(element) {        
   return element.value;                               
});
```

its only returning the `values` in this way,

```
["1"]
```

how can i return the result in *{"name": "value"}* pair.

Comment: Could you provide the JSON you are working with?

Comment: @MinistryofChaps what is there to provide? It is well documented in `serializeArray()` docs which always returns same structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the following?

```
var myArray = $.map(form_data, function(element) {        
   var elem = {};
   elem[element.name] = element.value;
   return elem;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are so close, create object with property and return it.

```
var myArray = $.map(form_data, function(element) {   
    var ob = {};  //Create object
    ob[element.name] = element.value; //Set element property
    return ob;  
});
```